# FTP client -- CR characters in gif is removed after get

Tags: c++, ftp

I'm creating an FTP client.

I'm getting a gif from the server, but after that the gif is corrupted.

When I change the file extension to look at the diff, I see that the 
CR/LF characters are gone.

[image: filemerge]

How could this be? I made sure to use image mode.

Here's my read code in TCP socket.

```
string TCPSocket::long_read()
{
    pollfd ufds;
    ufds.fd = sd;
    ufds.events = POLLIN;
    ufds.revents = 0;
    ssize_t bytesRead = 0;
    string result;
    char* buf = new char[LONGBUFLEN];
    do {
        bzero(buf, LONGBUFLEN);

        bytesRead = ::read(sd, buf, LONGBUFLEN);
        if (bytesRead == 0) {
            break;
        }
        if (bytesRead > 0) {
            result = result + string(buf, bytesRead);
        }
    } while (poll(&ufds, 1, 1000) > 0);
    return result;
}
```

Here my get code in main.cpp

```
    else if (command == command::GET) {
        string filename;
        cin >> filename;
        string dataHost;
        int dataPort;
        if (enterPassiveMode(dataHost, dataPort)) {
            dataSocket = new TCPSocket(dataHost.c_str(), dataPort);
            if (fork() == 0) {
                string result = dataSocket->long_read();
                size_t length = result.size();
                char* resultArr = new char[length];
                memcpy(resultArr, result.data(), length);

                //                    mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;
                FILE* file = fopen(filename.c_str(), "w+b");
                if (file) {
                    fwrite(resultArr, length, 1, file);
                    fclose(file);
                }
                else {
                    cout << "open failed";
                }
                break;
            }
            else {
                writeAndImmediateRead(rfc959::TYPE_I);
                controlSocket->write(rfc959::RETRIVE(filename));
                string result = controlSocket->read();
                cout << result;
                int reply = Parser::firstDigit(result);

                // I'll remove incomplete local file if request fails
                if (reply != rfc959::POSITIVE_PRELIMINARY_REPLY) {
                    remove(filename.c_str());
                    continue;
                }

                wait(NULL);
                cout << controlSocket->long_read();
            }
        }
    }
```

## EDIT

I did make sure to use Binary mode. And when I transferred a text file(though of a smaller size), it doesn't have this problem.  Here's the output:

[image: binarymode]

## EDIT 2

Output from Wireshark showing `Request: TYPE I` and `Response: Opening BINARY mode`

[image: wireshark]

Comment: You need to set BINARY mode rather than the default ASCII mode.

Comment: Why are you using `fork()` in your code?

Comment: @castaglia I'm using passive mode. The child has a one-time data connection while the parent holds the control connection.

Comment: @tomtom: please verify that you really send `TYPE I` to the server inside your application and that you get a successful response back. Because since it works from the command line I think that you are setting the type wrong. But my assumption is impossible to verify based on what you show.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I updated question to add output from wireshark showing `TYPE I` and the `200`,`150` Response

Comment: So your gif file is 965744 bytes big on the server side and on the client side it is smaller?  Is CRLF removed as you state in the title or is only CR removed? Did you count how many bytes you received in total and compared this to the number of bytes in the file you've written on disk? By answering all these questions you could detect on which step it goes wrong.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I wasn't sure which one when I was writing the title. I looked at the file and it [looks like only CR is removed](http://imgur.com/8ar46LC), and yes, it is [smaller on the client side](http://imgur.com/Nw2dxAw).

Comment: Does `result.size()` shows the expected size and only the written file is smaller or is `result.size()` already wrong?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Hmm, it is already wrong.

Comment: Did you count how many bytes you've received  (i.e. sum of bytesRead) to check if the CR went missing during transfer (incorrect image mode) or while appending to result?

Comment: What happens if you send `TYPE` _before_ sending `PASV`, rather than after?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich the sum of Bytes read is wrong too. Same number as `result.size()`

Comment: @Castaglia sending `TYPE I` before `PASV` doesn't affect the result

Comment: But you've checked that the command line version transferred the file correctly? If it did then please compare the commands (and their order) between your tool and the command line tool. And you could also see from wireshark how much bytes really where transferred in the data channel.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you!! I made a mistake while testing and the file on the server was, for some reason, already corrupt. I can verify that it works now.

Comment: so at least we learned something about how to narrow down where the problem is :)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes. Thank you so much! You're amazing

Answer (score 0):

By default, FTP servers and clients perform data transfers as "ASCII mode", which means that any CRLF sequence is translated on-the-fly to the host's ASCII line ending (*e.g.* just bare LF on Unix mmachines).  This behavior is mandated by [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959); see Section 3.1.1.1.

To transfer your data as *binary*, and avoid the ASCII mode translation, your FTP client will want to send the `TYPE` command first, *e.g.*:

```
TYPE I
```

Your `.gif` file should then be transferred as is, with no replacements/transformations on any CRLF sequences.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did make sure to use Binary mode. Edited question to show the output